# how to find the selected row index thus get items from the row in NatTable Grid?

Tags: swt, row, nattable

I've a problem to use the NatTable Grid i.e. High Performance SWT Grid which I downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nattable/files/NatTable/. I can load the data into this NatTable Grid, but I don't know(or find any method in NatTable) how to find the selected row's index as we do in case of Nebula Grid/SWT table. Moreover, how to extract the data from this Grid after filling it, so that the extracted row data can be loaded into an ArrayList. Please, somebody tell me the way I should follow to achieve these functionalities in NatTable.

Answer (score 1):

You can find answers to your questions in project examples, which are quite hard to find, but could be located through SVN browse on sourceforge.
You should look on event examples (there is [selection event example](http://nattable.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nattable/trunk/nattable/net.sourceforge.nattable.examples/src/net/sourceforge/nattable/examples/examples/_103_Events/Selection_events.java?revision=4175&view=markup)). Rest of examples are at [SVN repos on sourceforge](http://nattable.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nattable/trunk/nattable/net.sourceforge.nattable.examples/src/net/sourceforge/nattable/examples/examples/).

Comment: Thank you Sorceror for the answer. Actually I had already checked out whole nattable project from the official SVN repo http://sourceforge.net/projects/nattable/files/NatTable. However, due to some unknown reason, it didn't work properly. I'll try to what you've advised.

Comment: You're welcome. It was maybe some shutdown of sourceforge, try the SVN Browse feature in sourceforge web, works for most time..